# Arrange tick labels and square size in heat map using matplotlib pcolor

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, heatmap

I would like to make a heatmap looking like this.[image: Example Heat map]

So far I got the heat map but smaller squares and almost indistinguishable tick labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy as np
lbls = ['Li', 'Be', 'B', 'C', 'N', 'F', 'Na', 'Mg', 'Al', 'Si', 'P', 'S', 'Cl', 'K', 'Ca', 'Sc', 'Ti',
            'V', 'Cr', 'Mn', 'Fe', 'Co', 'Ni', 'Cu', 'Zn', 'Ga', 'Ge', 'As', 'Se', 'Br', 'Rb', 'Sr', 'Y',
            'Zr', 'Nb', 'Mo', 'Tc', 'Ru', 'Rh', 'Pd', 'Ag', 'Cd', 'In', 'Sn', 'Sb', 'Te', 'I', 'Cs', 'Ba',
            'Hf', 'Ta', 'W', 'Re', 'Os', 'Ir', 'Pt', 'Au', 'Hg', 'Tl', 'Pb', 'Bi', 'Po', 'At']

parr = np.random.random_integers(0,10,(63,63))
z_max = np.amax(parr)
z_min = np.amin(parr)
cbcolor = ['nipy_spectral','Greens','Blues','Reds']

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(15, 11)
ax.set_autoscale_on(False)

plot2 = pyplot.pcolor(parr, vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max,cmap=cbcolor[0])

pyplot.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(lbls)), lbls,rotation=90,fontsize=8)
pyplot.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(lbls)), lbls, fontsize=8)

pyplot.savefig("ploy.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

For the above code I get 
[image: Heat map]

Any help to get it more like the example plot with larger squares and more distinguished tick labels would be appreciated.

Comment: the ticks are possible but the square size only depends on the array you're plotting

Comment: Apparently both these images are of the same array size 63 X 63 with 3969 elements. However I will be content if I can get the ticks fixed.

Comment: My error I think they might have plotted a subset of that array. You are right it is 29 X 16 in the example